# MongooseError: Query was already executed:

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to update the document but the error says the query has already been executed.

*MongooseError: Query was already executed: footballs.updateOne({ date: 'January 4' }, {})*

```js
app.post('/api/bookslot', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    const token = req.headers['x-access-token'];
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'secret123');
    const email = decoded.email;
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: email });

    let sportname = req.body.selectedSport.toLowerCase();
    const time = req.body.slotTime;
    const seats = req.body.availableSeats - 1;

    if (!sportname.endsWith('s')) {
      sportname = sportname.concat('s');
    }
    const NewSlotModel = mongoose.model(sportname, slotSchema);
    var update = {};
    update[time] = seats - 1;
    console.log(update);
    const a = await NewSlotModel.updateOne(
      { date: req.body.slotDate },
      { $set: update },
      function (err, success) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
      }
    );

    return res.json({ status: 'ok' });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.json({ status: 'error' });
  }
});
```

where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using both async/await and callbacks in your code, causing mongoose to throw an error.
The actual effect of using them both is exactly the error type that you are receiving:

> Query was already executed

Mongoose v6 does not allow duplicate queries.

> Mongoose no longer allows executing the same query object twice. If
> you do, you'll get a Query was already executed error. Executing the
> same query instance twice is typically indicative of mixing callbacks
> and promises, but if you need to execute the same query twice, you can
> call Query#clone() to clone the query and re-execute it. See gh-7398

[Duplicate Query Execution](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#duplicate-query-execution)

To fix the issue, just remove the third argument from the await

> NewSlotModel.updateOne

Making it:

> ```
> const a = await NewSlotModel.updateOne(
>   { date: req.body.slotDate },
>   { $set: update }
> );
> ```

Comment: - Does this mean you lose the error handling function?
btw - thanks this solved my error

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose v6. Don't support callbacks any longer.. check the image.

```
const productCount = await Product.countDocuments((count) => count)  BAD

const productCount = await Product.countDocuments(); GOOD
```

[image]